# Zabbix email configuration

Tags: zabbix

[image]Our zabbix server is not sending e-mail notifications to the user through e-mail. 
SMTP is configured and working fine. From server backend, I am able to send and deliver mail. Have created item and trigger also but mails are not being sent yet.

Any help on this.

Comment: Could you share your Action configuration?

Comment: cannot connect to SMTP server "ip": cannot connect to [[ip]:25]: [111] Connection refused..We are getting this error on the action dashboard. We have configured the same server as smtp and zabbix is also installed on this.

Comment: Connection refused. If you telnet to ip:25 do you get the same error? Could be a firewall problem on the smtp machine?

Comment: it has been resolved now.. we just changed the smtp ip to localhost as it was configured on the same server as zabbix and it started working..thanks you.. :)